# Yocto- gcc cannot find shared library

Tags: c, embedded, shared-libraries, yocto, .so

I have a layer which creates a shared library (`libbbexample.so`) in `usr/lib` directory in a distribution build by Yocto. The library  contains several functions.

So I have created a new layer in which I have written a program which will use functions provided by `libbbexample.so`.

File `helloworld.c`:

```
#incude<stdio.h>
#include<bbexample.h>

int main()
{
    int data;
    
    data = get_data(); // this function is present in libbbexample.so 
    
    printf("data is %d",data);
    
    return 0;
}
```

So I have tried bitbake the new layer, but I am getting the error `"cannot find -libbbexample"`.

The contents of .bb files of new layer  are as follows

```
do_compile() {
    ${CC} helloworld.c -o helloworld -libbbexample ${LDFLAGS} 
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}
```

I have set the following priority for layers:

- priority of old layer (which will create the shared library) to 6;
- priority of new layer (which will make use shared library `libbbexample.so`) to 7.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added dependency of that layer?

Comment: no i have not added ,  since the old layer will generate the .so file, only when the image will be generated , i dont know about adding dependencies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add lib to your `gcc` command you have to trim the `lib` from the name.

Change

```
-libbbexample
```

with

```
-lbbexample
```

[The man](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) as reference.

If this is not enough you have to grand that `.so` file is compiled and installed before the `helloworld` example. You can use:

- [RDEPENDS](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-RDEPENDS)
- [DEPENDS](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-DEPENDS)

Comment: Since the .so file will be generated only when the whole yocto image is built , i dont know weather gcc will be able to find the .so file while bitbake the layer .

Comment: I'm not sure to getting you. You can avoid rebuilding the whole image. You can use `bitbake -c cleansstate` your_recipe_name to clean all files into temp/work directory. So `bitbake your_recipe_name` redo the whole job for your recipe.

Comment: No sir, what i was saying is that old layer will generate .so file and i can see the .so file only when i will flash the yocto image on the galileo board . so if i add a new layer to the  yocto , will it be able to find the .so file

Comment: Ok. So the problem is on the target device. But can be a problem only if you are bitbaking he `helloworld` recipe on the target. If you (as I guess) are  bitbaking the `helloworld` recipe on the host computer, the .so must be into the sysroot on the workbuild directory.  Could you clarify?

Comment: i am bitbaking the Helloworld recipie first and bitbaking the core-image at last  .

Comment: Still not clear to me. The process is, on a clean system: bitbake the core image and all libs/applications are compiled and installed. After that you have an image to be used on your target device. With an existent workbuild, you can manually build the lib recipe and after the helloworld recipe. BTW, as I wrote in my answer, RDEPENDS and DEPENDS make a recipe dependent on others.

Comment: As you have said -lbbexample and add DEPENDS = "bbexample-rt" , my build has compiled and image has been generated  , i need to flash the image on device and needs to check for output